# React crud changes history

Tags: reactjs, jsx, crud

I have this react crud app whats the best way to implement change history such that if I goto edit any records all the previous changes are visible.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-simple-crud?file=index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the backend then you would need to save the change history in the backend.

If do not have the backend or want to have change history on the frontend then you can use localstorage, though it will limited to that Browser on which the change is being.

The proper way is to use the backend and have a database, which sort of unique Id which identify the thing being edited and insert the previous values there, and when you want to show the changes made then fetch the changes from the database using the unique Id assigned.

Hope this answer your query.